# utility to check imports in python without running the code (python2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way to make sure all imports listed in all of my python files are in `PYTHONPATH`. Basically a validator for all my imports in files.

**My approach**:  Change all file path from / to "." e.g. foo/bar to foo.bar and then run:
`pkgutil.find_loader("foo.bar")`

**Problem**: It does not work if I have foo.bar.zoo.data as a module

```
export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd):"my_lib_path"
for root,dir,files in os.walk(work_dir):
        for filename in files:
            if not "__init__" in filename and filename.endswith(".py"):
               print "Testing file {}".format(os.path.join(root,filename))
               filepath = os.path.join(root,filename)
               filepath = filepath.replace(work_dir,'',)
               filepath = filepath.replace('/', '.')
               filepath = filepath.lstrip(".").rstrip(".py")
               print " testing filepath" , filepath
               # tried this also 
               '''for imp, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules(root):
                   full_name = "{}.{}".format(root,name)
               '''    module = imp.find_module(full_name)
               mod = pkgutil.find_loader(filepath)
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is to use the [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) (Python 3.1+) or [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) (Python 2.x) module to do all the steps an `import` would do up to, but not including, running the code.

The key functions for each Python version are:

- 3.4-3.8: [`importlib.util.find_spec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec)
- 3.3-3.3: [`importlib.find_loader`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/importlib.html#importlib.find_loader).
- 3.1-3.2: [`importlib.find_module`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.PathFinder.find_module)
- 3.0-3.0: [`imp.find_module`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/imp.html#imp.find_module)
- 1.5-2.7: [`imp.find_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module)
- 0.9-1.4: No idea. (There were no packages yet; everything was different…)

---

Advantages of doing it this way:

- It works whether the module is a normal Python module, a `.pyc`-only module, a C extension module, a builtin, or some funky special type of module that you've installed a custom import hook for.
- It works even if the module is inside a `.egg`, or in the frozen bootstrap collection, or if the whole library is wrapped up in a `.zip` or even buried inside a `.exe`.
- It automatically takes care of the funky rules, like figuring out what is or isn't a valid namespace package extension directory (including dealing with things like `site.py` and old-style `setuptools` path-injection) that would be a huge pain to get right.

---

In 3.4+, this is literally the same code that `import` uses, because the entire import system is written in Python. For older versions, that's not true—but for 2.3+, it's guaranteed to get you the same thing you would get in an import hook, which is almost surely close enough.

---

Quoting the 3.7 docs:

> `importlib.util.find_spec(name, package=None)`
>
> Find the spec for a module, optionally relative to the specified **package** name. If the module is in `sys.modules`, then `sys.modules[name].__spec__` is returned (unless the spec would be `None` or is not set, in which case `ValueError` is raised). Otherwise a search using `sys.meta_path` is done. `None` is returned if no spec is found.
>
> If **name** is for a submodule (contains a dot), the parent module is automatically imported.
>
> **name** and **package** work the same as for `import_module()`.

(You don't really have to care what a spec is here; if Python can find the spec for a module, the module is present; if it returns `None`, the module is not present.)

So, this will just magically handle `foo.bar.zoo.data`.

If you look at the [Examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#checking-if-a-module-can-be-imported), there's one that does exactly what you want, "Checking if a module can be imported".

```
def test_module(name):
    if not importlib.util.find_spec(name):
        raise ImportError(name)
```

---

From the 2.7 docs:

> `imp.find_module(name[, path])`
>
> Try to find the module *name*. If *path* is omitted or `None`, the list of directory names given by `sys.path` is searched, but first a few special places are searched: the function tries to find a built-in module with the given name (`C_BUILTIN`), then a frozen module (`PY_FROZEN`), and on some systems some other places are looked in as well (on Windows, it looks in the registry which may point to a specific file).
>
> Otherwise, *path* must be a list of directory names; each directory is searched for files with any of the suffixes returned by `get_suffixes()` above. Invalid names in the list are silently ignored (but all list items must be strings).
>
> If search is successful, the return value is a 3-element tuple `(file, pathname, description)`:
>
> *file* is an open file object positioned at the beginning, *pathname* is the pathname of the file found, and *description* is a 3-element tuple as contained in the list returned by `get_suffixes()` describing the kind of module found.
>
> If the module does not live in a file, the returned *file* is `None`, *pathname* is the empty string, and the *description* tuple contains empty strings for its suffix and mode; the module type is indicated as given in parentheses above. If the search is unsuccessful, `ImportError` is raised. Other exceptions indicate problems with the arguments or environment.
>
> If the module is a package, *file* is `None`, *pathname* is the package path and the last item in the *description* tuple is `PKG_DIRECTORY`.
>
> This function does not handle hierarchical module names (names containing dots). In order to find *P.M*, that is, submodule *M* of package *P*, use `find_module()` and `load_module()` to find and load package *P*, and then use `find_module()` with the *path* argument set to `P.__path__`. When *P* itself has a dotted name, apply this recipe recursively.

As you can see, it's a little more complicated—it doesn't magically handle `foo.bar.zoo.data`; you will need to find `foo`, verify that it's a package, load it, find `bar`, etc., and finally find (but not load) `data`.

Something like this (untested):

```
def test_module(name):
    parts = name.split('.')
    path = None
    for part in parts[:-1]:
        file, pathname, description = imp.find_module(part, path)
        if description[-1] != imp.PKG_DIRECTORY:
            raise ImportError(name)
        pkg = imp.load_module(part, file, pathname, description)
        path = pkg.__path__
    file, pathname, description = imp.find_module(part[-1], path)
```

Comment: i looked at it actually i think importlib.util.find_spec was introduce in python3+ . unfortunately i am using python 2.7

Comment: @Stock So you have to use `imp` instead. I've edited the answer to point at the function you want. No example in the docs to copy and paste, and it doesn't quite handle everything 100% the same way as `import` itself does, but it should be all you need.

Comment: @Stock Rewrote it to cover 2.7 more directly.

Comment: Thanks for the smaple above, so the call  pkg = imp.load_module(part, file, pathname, description)  returns a a tuple and pkg.__path__ does now work unfortunately, i tried to take pick items from the tuple but no luck :(

Comment: @Stock `imp.load_module` returns a tuple? That’s not what the docs say. And not what I see on any 2.7 I have, or what [this blog author sees](https://pymotw.com/2/imp/), and I can’t find anything online about that. What is the tuple it returns?