# Validating python imports - why this ambiguity?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-importlib

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491793/utility-to-check-imports-in-python-without-running-the-code-python2-7) question, I want to validate that certain libraries are installed in python 3.x before continuing. The following works... but not without a lot of head-scratching:

```py
# standard imports ------------------------------------------------------------
import sys, logging, importlib.util
from time import sleep

# test non-standard libraries for existance prior to load
SPEC = importlib.util.find_spec("pyserial")  # yes, pyserial?!
if SPEC is not None:
    print("\nSerial I/O library not found... install with 'python3 -m pip install pyserial'\n")
    exit()
else: import serial     # why not pyserial?
SPEC = importlib.util.find_spec("Colorama") # "Colorama" MUST be capitalized!
if SPEC is not None:
    print("\nColorama library not found... install with 'python3 -m pip install colorama'\n")
    exit()
else: from colorama import init, deinit, Fore, Style # must NOT be capitalized!
```

Could someone please explain why:

- "pyserial" must be used for `importlib`, while "serial" for the `import`, and
- "**C**olorama" must be used for `importlib`, while "**c**olorama" for that `import`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  `importlib.util.find_spec('Colorama')` returns `None` whereas `importlib.util.find_spec('colorama')` returns the module.

Comment: Think I'm noticing some further ambiguity between Win10 and Lubuntu implementations.